# windows phone 8 - How to display longitude and latitude coordinates on map (current location)

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8, geolocation, maps, latitude-longitude

Is there any way to display coordinates that i get from my current location on a simple map in c# windows phone 8 application?

This is the code that i use to get my current location. For now it only displays coordinates in textblock, but i need to convert it to display position on map.

```
private async void GetCurrentLocation()
    {
        Geolocator locationFinder = new Geolocator();
        try
        {
            Geoposition currentLocation = await locationFinder.GetGeopositionAsync(
            maximumAge: TimeSpan.FromSeconds(120),
            timeout: TimeSpan.FromSeconds(10));
            String longitude = currentLocation.Coordinate.Longitude.ToString("0.00");
            String latitude = currentLocation.Coordinate.Latitude.ToString("0.00");
            MyTextBlock.Text = "Long: " + longitude + "Lat: " + latitude;
        }
        catch (UnauthorizedAccessException)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("And exception occured!");
        }
    }
```

**Any help is appreciated!Thanks!**

Comment: In other words do you wanted to test it on a map?

Comment: @Kulasangar exactly. my goal is to display that location on a map

Comment: I've posted a suggestion below!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If so you could use a `PushPin` to show the current location on a `map`.

Reference : [Windows Phone : Location : Map : Pushpin](http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/806054/Windows-Phone-Location-Map-Pushpin)

Comment: Thank you...This does the job. But somehow...that's not my location as i thought it would be...it's just some random location near Seattle...just like in your example. I need to display my current location :(

Comment: Did you try doing it through your `Emulator`? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21659312/

Comment: that seems to solve problem, but only temporary. whenever i exit the application and restart it, it shows the "redmond" location again and i have to go and set new location again. Not the best solution imo, as it does not find your location on your own, it just shows the location that you marked previously.

Comment: May be you are not initializer the function that sets the position in the right place. Try placing the call in the NavigatedTo or Initialize procedures... works for my like that!